# Connotation of "unzipping"

Tags: connotation, innuendo

I'm working a piece of software that, as part of what it does, will extract/uncompress a ZIP file. I'd like to report this to the user by showing the word "unzipping" alone.

**Will displaying the word "unzipping" alone, with little further context, have any unwanted sexual innuendos and/or sound funny to a native speaker? If so, how strong would the innuendo be?**

The closest questions I could find here is  [Compressed vs. zipped](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80190/compressed-vs-zipped/80197#80197), but that doesn't answer my question.

For the sake of completeness, 1) the file is always a ZIP file, "unzipping" seems to be the correct word to use, 2) using "extracting" instead would be my second choice, but I worry if it would end up being misinterpreted as something along the lines of "extracting information from data", which will happen later on, 3) I could say "extracting [the] ZIP file", but have a somewhat limited space to show this in, and 4) I'm just really curious.

Comment: If you are clearly referring to a file...why should it create a misunderstanding? Unzip is the correct term to use: 
(Computer Science) computing (tr) to decompress (a file) that had previously been zipped

Comment: Decompressing or unpacking might work, if you really want to avoid unzipping. But really: if your users are going to giggle when they see they word _"unzipping"_, that's their problem. Just tell them to grow up

Comment: At least USB sticks took care of the "insert your floppy"

Comment: no sexual innuendos, you're all set

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, but it is also the correct term for unzipping one's fly, as far as I can tell. Also, the word would be displayed alone. The other meaning occurred to me, a non-native speaker, and it's hard for me to judge how native speakers would see it, though I had my opinion. I'm sure many innocent phrases ended up being rather unfortunate, and I'd rather play it safe.

Comment: *un-Zipping* might do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Unzipping* is a commonly used and well understood term for this context, with no sexual implications.  If you are really uncomfortable with it, you might use *expanding* or *decompressing.*

Speaking as a native speaker of American English, while I can easily picture *unzipping* in a sexual context, I don't consider it a term that is intrinsically likely to be interpreted that way.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer as it is the first response to actually answer the question rather than just providing suggestions and as it elaborates on the connotations. Thanks!