# Is there a word for made up verbs that end in "ing"?

Tags: single-word-requests, morphology, verbing, antimeria

One thing I love about English is that verbs can be easily created just by adding the suffix "-ing" and adjectives by adding "-ly".

How would you call this phenomenon?

Examples:

> - Googling, Youtubing
> - Pants-shittingly

Comment: Verbing weirds language.

Comment: Is your question about what you call the words which result [as per question title], or what you call the process itself [as per question body]?

Comment: "Pants-shittingly" You just earned a +1 for expanding my vocabulary.

Comment: @DrydenLong – Your vocabulary has not improved; only your grammatical techniques.

Comment: @Andrew Leach - I was asking about the words itself, but a word for the process could be interesting too. I think I didn't pay enough attention to what I was writing when I asked this question.

Comment: Great. My answer isn't entirely wasted then! :-)

Comment: related: [Should Capitals be Used When Verbing Trademarks?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15458/should-capitals-be-used-when-verbing-trademarks)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

verb + -ing is called a [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund):

> As applied to English, it refers to the -ing form of a verb when it is used, as a verb, to form a noun phrase (for example, the verb learning in the sentence "Learning English is an easy process for some")

These are **not** verbs; they are nouns. You can't say "I Googling the definition" or "You should Googling it." It is a noun, as in "Googling is useful."

Also, adding -ly does **not** make it an adjective; it makes it an adverb. There is no special term for adverbs ending in -ly, although most of them do.

About the "made up" part - you're not really making new words; you're just taking made-up words and adding -ing or -ly, so there's not really anything special about this. If you consider Google a normal verb, then there's nothing special.

Comment: Adding *-ly* to a noun does make an adjective. Adding *-ly* to an adjective makes an adverb.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for pointing this out, I confused verbs with nouns for some reason.
Also, as JSBձոգչ wrote, adding "-ly" to a noun does make an adjective.

Comment: Yes, and it's also not true that any verb with -ing is a gerund. There are [at least 5 quite different kinds of English lexical items that have that form](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html), and they work and mean very different things. Gerunds are one of them, for sure. But many of these are derived nouns.

Comment: "Googling" isn't exactly a noun.  What about the sentence: "I _am_ Googling the definition"?  You couldn't call it a noun in that context.

Answer (score 6):

It's ***being productive***:

> **productive** *adjective*
>   **1** ...
>   *Linguistics* (of a prefix, suffix, or other linguistic unit) currently used in forming new words or expressions:
>   *many suffixes are common and productive*

I suppose the phenomenon itself might be *production*, but I've never come across the word in a Linguistics sense.

Comment: @fixer1234 If I flag that comment as Too Chatty or Not Constructive, it will disappear instantly.