# I am writing a story about my Barbie do I use a capital

Tags: orthography, capitalization, trademarks

I am doing an assignment and I have to say my barbie doll. Would the word barbie be a capital?

Comment: Generally speaking, one would capitalize "Barbie", when referring to the doll.  There are circumstances where, to achieve a desired effect in a story, it would not be capitalized, but that's moderately advanced stuff.

Comment: Goodness gracious me. Did absolutely everyone on this page just completely miss the single point that actually matters? Barbie **is a name**. That is all there is to it. Instead people come up with all kinds of reasons that don't hold any water upon the most superficial of inspections, or are indeed horribly wrong. Surely we as a community can do better than that?

Comment: @RegDwigнt: In fact, that's not all there is to it. As I noted in my answer, "Xerox" and "Velcro" were names that have now become words, and as such are commonly not capitalized. Likewise, acronyms such as "SONAR", "RADAR", "LASER", and "PIN" are typically lower-cased in general usage. I certainly know people who always capitalize nouns based on names, but saying all name-based terms are always capitalized is naive.

Comment: @MichaelS I surmise what RegDwigнt means is that Barbie as it refers to as the character is a person's name, which is always a proper noun and since in all cases, the Barbie in the phrase refers to the character, you always capitalize Barbie. The trademark rule becomes irrelevant because of that and acronyms were never relevant even since the beginning. However, what should be done with the word "doll" in the phrase remains in question …

Comment: @Tonepoet: As I pointed out in my answer, even in the context of Mattel dolls, "Barbie" refers to the trademark in like 99% of cases, not the character. So it's the trademark name, not the character name, that's relevant in those cases. Further, it commonly refers to any Barbie®-like doll, in which case neither the trademark name nor the character name is directly relevant. Acronyms are relevant because the "rule" for lower-casing them is exactly the same as that for lower-casing names. I'm not sure what issue there is with "doll" though. It's always lower-cased that I've seen, even by Mattel.

Comment: @MichaelS There is a difference between a word like xerox, velcro, or google, which have become genericised words for products or actions, and Barbie, which does not appear to have been genericised. A Barbie doll is a certain kind of doll, not all the dolls in that category. You can't claim that any random doll would be referred to as a barbie doll (at least, not on a consistent enough basis to call the usage standard and not an error).

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: I *can* claim that, because it's true. Walk into any random house with a bunch of dolls laying on the floor, and listen to Mom or Dad telling the kids to clean up "the barbie dolls" even when two-thirds of them aren't Barbie® dolls. I've heard it a thousand times. I've also repeatedly seen people insist "Xerox", "Velcro" and "Google" are proper nouns, not verbs, and not generic. I've seen *many* people on *numerous* occasions go out of their way to avoid genericizing trademarked names. There isn't one right answer here, and the most superficial of inspections shows that.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New 安宇 That's the crux of the matter. There's a legal issue; blithely stating 'Oh, everybody does it' could lead to legal redress. I don't know how to discover whether genericisation has taken place (perhaps writing to the company for their views?) But I know genericisation has been covered here before.

Answer (score 4):

You should capitalise 'Barbie' in ['Barbie doll'](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/barbie-doll), because that is how the dictionary styles the word. Also, a ['barbie'](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/barbie) refers informally to a barbecue in Australian English.

Comment: So what does it mean when an aussie writes "Throw another shrimp on the Barbie"?

Comment: @deadrat it means [they're quoting an ad using American English for an American audience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrimp_on_the_barbie)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Sorry, I'm just too damn old to learn how to use emoticons.

Comment: @deadrat No worries.

Comment: @deadrat - But do we actually write that? "Shrimps" are **not** generally in our vernacular, we tend to say "Prawns". According to the [https://museumvictoria.com.au/discoverycentre/infosheets/what-is-the-difference-between-prawns-and-shrimp/] Museum of Victoria (Australia) "A shrimp in the USA is a prawn in Australia! ... Paul Hogan made the word familiar in Australia with his expression ‘Throw another shrimp on the barbie!’"

Comment: @lithic A couple of *shrimp* — **NOTE:** no *-s* for the plural on the critter! — are two decapod crustaceans, whereas a couple of *shrimp**s*** are just a pair of skinny guys.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should use the capital. "Barbie" is a trademarked product:

[Mattel trademarks](http://corporate.mattel.com/our-toys/trademark.aspx)

Chicago Manual of Style says that trademarked names should be capitalized:

[Chicago Manual of Style: Registered Trademarks](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/RegisteredTrademarks.html)

Comment: So. You are saying we must at all times capitalize *escalator, cellophane, videotape, heroin, kerosene, hoover, app,* as well as *office, apple*, and *word*. You are also saying that everyone, before using any word, must first check back with every patent Office in the World. I think I am going with −1 on this.

Comment: @RegDwight, of course not. I'm answering the specific question that the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

There are different thoughts here. First, let's define "b/Barbie doll".

1. Barbie® is a [brand name owned by Mattel](http://barbie.mattel.com) that includes everything from [dolls](http://barbie.mattel.com/shop/en-us/ba/all-barbie-dolls#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&orderBy:&pageView:grid&minPrice:&maxPrice:&pageSize:&contentPageSize:&) to [iPhone cases](http://barbie.mattel.com/shop/en-us/ba/clothing-accessories/barbie-case-for-iphone-cmk35) to a [driveable dune buggy](http://barbie.mattel.com/shop/en-us/ba/bikes-outdoor/power-wheels-barbie-dune-racer-y9367) (I *so* wanted one of those as a kid).

   - A Barbie® doll is a doll sold under the Barbie® brand name.
2. The Barbie universe is a fictional world the stories of the Barbie® dolls are set in. I don't know what kind of [canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_(fiction)) exists for this universe, or how tightly such canon is set, but it exists at some level.

   - Since the dolls represent real humans inside the Barbie universe, I don't think it makes much sense to talk about "Barbie dolls" in this context.
3. Barbie is the name of a fictional character in the Barbie universe. Presumably, the Barbie® brand name is based on the Barbie character.

   - A Barbie doll is any doll representing the Barbie character.
   - A Barbie doll could be any doll named Barbie, or a doll representing any other character named Barbie, but this is unlikely in practice.
   - A Barbie doll doesn't have to be a Barbie®-brand doll, but generally is.
4. "Barbie" can generically refer to any Barbie®-like product, fashion, or other thing.

   - "Barbie doll" could refer to an extremely thin, possibly anorexic, fashion model, or anyone else with atypical proportions, especially in the context of said proportions being extreme and in-fashion.
   - "Barbie doll" could refer to role-playing or other acting in a manner consistent with children playing with Barbie® dolls.
   - "barbie doll" could refer to any kind of children's doll intended to be played with in a role-play manner, especially if the doll is targeted at girls<sup>1</sup>, involves fashion and/or makeup, is approximately a foot tall, and/or is modeled with exaggerated or non-realistic proportions.

There are probably other definitions that make sense here, but this should be good enough to get the point across.

**For most of these uses, the name should be capitalized as "Barbie"**, and possibly have a registered trademark symbol like "Barbie®" or "Barbie™" <sup>2</sup> <sup>3</sup>.

**For the generic use, the word should probably be the lower-case "barbie doll"**. This follows the general trend<sup>4</sup> of lower-casing "velcro", "xerox" and other brand names that have become general-purpose words, except when used to explicitly refer to the brand or product the word came from. Note that **the generic use can still apply to Barbie®-brand dolls if it's unimportant what brand the dolls are**. For example, I could say, "I used to launch my sister's barbie dolls in the air with model rockets so they could be astronauts", even though my sister had actual Barbie® dolls, because it was the act of launching dolls on rockets that's important, not the brand name.

**If you want to be accurate while avoiding controversy, you could refer to non-Barbie® barbie dolls as "fashion dolls"**, "action figures", "action dolls", "children's dolls", "girls' dolls" <sup>1</sup>, "family dolls", or something similar, just as people "correctly" refer to velcro as "hook and loop fastener". However, the concept of a "barbie doll" is much more specific than these terms; "action figures/dolls" could refer to soldiers like G.I. Joe, "children's/girl's dolls" could refer to baby dolls, etc.

Personally, I find "fashion doll", from the Wikipedia article on [Barbie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbie), to be the best generic match to the Barbie concept. According to Wikipedia, the original Barbie doll was marketed as a "Teen-age Fashion Model", and the Barbie® website currently considers Barbie to be "the ultimate fashion icon" <sup>3</sup>, so it seems Mattel would probably agree with this term.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Not that I would ever advocate gender-specific toys or playstyles. Nor am I suggesting girls don't play with G.I. Joes or Legos, or that boys don't play with Barbie dolls and Fisher Price kitchen sets. But the Barbie® line-up has historically been targeted at and marketed for female children.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> In general, I would avoid the symbol except when initially introducing the brand name just because it looks really annoying in practice, but it's not inherently wrong to write it everywhere. An exception I'd make is a document where the distinction between the Barbie character and the Barbie® brand is consistently necessary, such as this answer. Note that even the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/RegisteredTrademarks.html), which disagrees with ever using a lower-case for things like "I googled it", agrees that trademark symbols can be omitted for typical writing.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> I'm not sure the distinction between "Barbie™" and "Barbie®" in practice, but I've seen both on Mattel's site.</sub>

> <sub>Welcome to The Barbie™ Collection! Find the latest Barbie® dolls and accessories for Barbie doll collectors and fans of Barbie, the ultimate fashion icon!</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup> This practice is still [highly contested](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15458/should-capitals-be-used-when-verbing-trademarks), especially by [the trademark holders](http://jcp.proscenia.net/publications/articles_mlr/walsh/Trademark_Battles.html). But the practice itself is quite real.</sub>

Comment: 'For the generic use, the word should probably be the lower-case "barbie doll." ' Are you aware that Biro successfully sued at least one person using a small 'b', successfully fighting off attempted genericisation? This is a legal rather than English language issue; are you sure you have your legal facts right?